# Cant add border to Button using XML

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I just wanted to add a broder to my Button but its not working.

Main xml script:

[image]

button_style4.xml:

[image]

The Button appears normaly in the App and it works as I want it to work just the border is not appearing...
Someone find the fault?

Comment: its not a duplicate! It is just not working in the way everybody says

Answer (score 0):

```
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@drawable/button_border"
    android:text="Example"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    style="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"
    />
```

Comment: not working pls look at my code